# Regex to gather text within multiple pipes

Tags: regex, perl, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I have text that I need to match on in between the pipes. I have tried `\|[^|]+\|`, but that doesn't seem to gather each one.

```
|N/A|text123|text1235|Medium|1|Medium|test123|test456|test|test|test|http|tcp|
```

Comment: What about just `/[^|]+/g`? What is your environment? Please share the current code that fails.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a job for [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

```
my @items = split /\|/, $string;

print "$_\n" for @items;
```

Output:

```
N/A
text123
text1235
Medium
1
Medium
test123
test456
test
test
test
http
tcp
```

As far as a regex, this should work:

```
my @items = /[^|]+/g;
```

Comment: `my @items = split /\|/, $string; shift(@items);` or `my @items = split /\|/, substr($string, 1);` would be needed to account for the leading `|`.

Comment: Or `shift @items if $items[0] eq '|';` to allow for there not being a leading `|`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    [^\|]+
```

I.e. Match anything except pipes

Comment: That will only grab the first match. You need the `/g` (global) modifier to get all matches (I believe that's what the OP is asking for anyhow).

Comment: Oh yes.  Makes sense.  I was debugging using https://regex101.com/ which has /g set by default.  Thanks!